# “Uno dei più grandi fisici” o “una delle più grandi fisiche”, detto di una donna?

Tags: word-choice, gender

Nell'ambito di un uso non sessista della lingua italiana, in cui se si parla di una persona di sesso femminile appartenente alla Camera dei deputati o all'avvocatura la si chiama “deputata” o “avvocata”, in cui si cerca di privilegiare le forme neutre a quelle maschili e così via, quale ritenete che sia la formulazione migliore tra le seguenti?

> Lise Meitner fu uno dei più grandi fisici nucleari del Novecento.

(Era una donna e quindi si vorrebbe evitare di chiamarla “fisico”.)

> Lise Meitner fu una delle più grandi fisiche nucleari del Novecento.

(Sembra che la si stia confrontando solo con le altre fisiche, mentre l'intenzione è di dire che fu una delle persone più grandi in assoluto in quel settore.)

O un'altra formulazione ancora, che però sia sempre concisa, quasi come uno slogan per mettere in evidenza l'importanza della Meitner (e quindi cercando di evitare sia cose come “fisiche e fisici” che perifrasi come quella che ho usato sopra con “persone che si occupano etc.”)?

Comment: Interessante. Anch'io intuitivamente darei due significati diversi alle due frasi.

Comment: La prima, senza dubbio.

Comment: Anch'io direi la prima, anche se stona. Sono infatti d'accordo che la seconda abbia significato diverso. I collettivi con elementi sia maschili che femminili vogliono il maschile (che in questi casi fa da neutro). Uno può sempre schivare l'ostacolo dicendo «_Lise Meitner fu una delle più grandi menti della fisica nucleare del Novecento_» o «_Lise Meitner fu una delle menti più brillanti della fisica nucleare del Novecento_», ma è un trucco e non risponde davvero alla domanda.

Comment: @bobie: 1) È esattamente l'esempio che mi interessava porre. 2) Se trovi buffo “fisica” (ma non per esempio “biologa”), abituatici, perché vedrai sempre più spesso simili parole buffe. 3) Se il problema fosse che lo stesso termine ha più significati, dovremmo abolire mezza lingua italiana: parole come “vite”, “radio”, “parto”, “venti”, “porta”, “casta” e infinite altre, tra cui... “fisico” («La moglie di Einstein ci teneva al suo fisico»). E infine, 4) Più in generale, la linguistica può essere più descrittiva o più prescrittiva, ma la categoria del “buffo” ne esula un po'.

Comment: @bobie e DaG, questa discussione è fuori dallo scopo della domanda. Per favore, leggete questo: http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cerco di esplorare le varie possibilità.

Se dici

> *Lise Meitner fu **uno** dei più grandi **fisici** nucleari del Novecento*

stai dicendo che Lise Meitner fu un uomo, e la cosa disturba.

Se dici

> *Lise Meitner fu **una** delle più grandi **fisiche** nucleari del Novecento.*

stai dicendo che Lise Meitner fu importante limitatamente al sottoinsieme femminile delle persone che si occupavano di fisica. Per confermare questa interpretazione, considera ad esempio Rita Levi Montalcini (2008), *Le tue antenate*, Carlo Gallucci editore, dove a pagina 30 si legge

> «Maria Cunitz fu la più importante astronoma di quei tempi»

ed è chiaro che non può significare che fosse superiore a Giovanni Keplero, Galileo Galilei o Isaac Newton.

Alternativamente potresti dire

> *Lise Meitner fu **una** dei più grandi **fisici** nucleari del Novecento*

e stai dicendo che fu donna e fu importante tra fisici, uomini e donne. Stona la costruzione *una (femminile) dei (maschile)* ma forse è il massimo di correttezza politica di genere a cui puoi ambire in italiano dove, notoriamente, la regola è quella di usare il sostantivo maschile plurale per indicare collettivi di genere diverso.

A sostegno di questa scelta, che forse in futuro sarà quella che prevarrà, puoi cercare su [Google](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22una+tra+i+pi%C3%B9%22) per verificarne l'uso (con l'accortezza di scartare i tanti errori che pure vi si incontrano). Per esempio:

- «Franziska Van Almsick, destinata a impadronirsi della scena internazionale per lo straordinario appeal che la renderà una dei più ricercati personaggi simbolo del nuoto e dello sport mondiale» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nuoto_(Enciclopedia-dello-Sport)/))
- «[Gae Aulenti] è diventata una tra i più importanti e significativi esponenti dell'architettura moderna» ([la Repubblica](http://www.repubblica.it/persone/2012/11/01/news/e_morta_gae_aulenti-45711755/))
- «solo la settimana scorsa Intesa Sanpaolo, una dei più grandi istituti italiani, ha annunciato» ([la Repubblica](http://www.repubblica.it/economia/affari-e-finanza/2014/03/17/news/telefonino_e_dati_in_cloud_lo_sportello_digitale_e_la_filiale_cambia_pelle-81175304/))
- «L'ha scritto una tra i più colti giornalisti italiani, Marina Valensise» ([Corriere della Sera](http://www.corriere.it/cultura/libri/12_marzo_14/cazzullo-napoli-primavera-sicilia-estate_0b253150-6de4-11e1-98c2-a788cd669a01.shtml))
- « È bionda, ha 39 anni, è madre di due bambine: ed è anche una dei più feroci 'serial killer' della Russia» ([Corriere della Sera](http://www.corriere.it/cronache/10_giugno_08/russia-serial-killer-vecchiette_0c88f4fa-72ff-11df-80b7-00144f02aabe.shtml))
- «All’epoca [Caterina] Ferrero era assessore regionale ai Lavori pubblici ed era considerata una tra i possibili candidati alla Provincia nel 2004» ([Il Fatto Quotidiano](http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2011/06/15/scandalo-sanita-arrestata-a-torino-lex-assessore-pdl-ferrero/118300/))
- «Il Washington Post, in un lungo articolo, ripercorre la vita di “una dei più influenti scienziati della sua generazione, particolarmente ammirevole per gli ostacoli che, quando iniziò la sua carriera, le donne di tutto il mondo incontravano lavorando nella scienza”» ([Il Fatto Quotidiano](http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2012/12/31/montalcini-nyt-rivoluzionaria-nello-studio-del-cervello-oggi-camera-ardente/458605/), su Rita Levi Montalcini)

---

Se questa soluzione non soddisfa, volendo schivare l'ostacolo, si potrebbe dire

> *Lise Meitner fu una delle più grandi menti della fisica nucleare del Novecento*

o

> *Lise Meitner fu una delle menti più brillanti della fisica nucleare del Novecento*

ma questo trucco, che non risponde davvero alla domanda, non fa che esaltare il fatto che, quando un elemento di genere grammaticale femminile è presente insieme ad un collettivo di genere misto, o accetti la regola menzionata su, sul maschile plurale, oppure sei costretto ad esprimerti in maniera più creativa e distrarre il destinatario del messaggio con qualche fuoco d'artificio.

---

@Elberich, non sono sicuro che questo sia lo spazio più adatto per esprimere opinioni "politiche". L'esigenza di neutralizzare il linguaggio dal punto di vista del genere esiste in tutto il mondo ed è fenomeno rilevante in quanto il dibattito che ne segue modifica il modo di parlare in lingua italiana: qualche link che mostra fino a che livelli ciò accade (Treccani, Accademia della Crusca, istituzioni UE, pubblica amministrazione, etc.):

- [Alma Sabatini, Il sessismo nella lingua italiana](http://www.funzionepubblica.gov.it/media/962032/il%20sessismo%20nella%20lingua%20italiana.pdf)
- [Parlamento europeo, La neutralità di genere nel linguaggio usato al Parlamento europeo](http://ec.europa.eu/translation/italian/rei/drafting/documents/neutralita_genere_it.pdf)
- [Cecilia Robustelli, Il sessimo nella lingua italiana](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/speciali/femminile/Robustelli.html)
- [Cecilia Robustelli, Linee guida per l’uso del genere nel linguaggio amministrativo](http://www.rai.it/dl/docs/1354527785476guida_robustelli.pdf)

Comment: @DaG: Anche in *Donne, grammatica e media. Suggerimenti per l’uso dell’italiano*, di Cecilia Robustelli, che si può scaricare da [questo sito](http://giulia.globalist.it/Detail_News_Display?ID=77798&typeb=0&La-grammatica-che-rispetta-le-donne), appare questo esempio: «Alessandra Ballerini è *una di quei professionisti* che ha deciso di occuparsi delle persone, prima ancora che dei loro guai giudiziari.»

Answer (score 4):

Mi sembra giusto porsi il problema :-) Senz'altro **non** si può usare

> "Lise Meitner fu uno dei più grandi fisici nucleari del Novecento."

La femminilizzazione della lingua non si liquida con criteri estetici ("è brutto, suona male, è buffo"); la presenza sempre più frequente delle donne in posizioni e ruoli prima non ricoperti la impone; il linguaggio rende visibili tali ruoli (tanto più che l'italiano prevede il maschile e il femminile tra i generi grammaticali...).

Essendo il maschile il genere inclusivo (sic!), siamo d'accordo che "i più grandi fisici" contiene scienziati della fisica uomini e donne. Quindi se il senso della frase è esprimere l'appartenenza di Lise Meitner all'insieme dei più grandi fisici, si sostituisca "*una di*" o "*uno di*" con "*essere tra*":

> "Lise Meitner fu tra i più grandi fisici nucleari del Novecento."

oppure

> "Lise Meitner si annovera tra i più grandi fisici nucleari del Novecento."

Oltre al tuo caso specifico, anche negli altri esempi giornalistici l'uso "*si annovera tra*"  "*appartiene a*", "*è tra*" avrebbe avuto la stessa valenza di "*una/uno dei*", col vantaggio però che la forma è epicena, contrariamente a "*una/uno dei*".

Comment: [Epicèno](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/E/epiceno.php) è sinonimo di _ambigenere_ (in senso grammaticale).