# Sull'uso dei diversi modi di coniugare il verbo soddisfare

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs

Quando ho letto [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/2390/707) mi sono sorpresa di trovare la frase

> «Se questa soluzione non *soddisfa*, ...»

perché qui io avrei messo *soddisfà*. Ho cercato la [coniugazione del verbo soddisfare](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ITverbs.aspx?v=soddisfare) e ho trovato che ammette diverse forme. La mia domanda è: tutte queste forme sono usate in modo uguale in tutti i registri della lingua? Alcune forme sono più formali delle altre? Alcune forme sono cadute in disuso?

Comment: *soddisfà', con l'accento sulla 'a' non si usa, ma sono sicuro che tanti tanti anni fa i maestri delle elementari segnavano l'assenza dell'accento come errore grave. Erano altri tempi.

Comment: Prova a leggere alcuni articoli di matematica scritti in italiano. Il verbo *soddisfare* viene usato spessissimo in questo contesto, basti pensare a: *soddisfare un'equazione*, *un sistema*, *una formula*, *un assioma* ecc. Non ho *mai* visto mettere l'accento in tali circostanze (e ne ho letti un po').

Comment: Dunque, si può affermare che alcune delle forme di coniugare il verbo soddisfare (e non mi riferisco soltanto alla terza persona singolare del presente indicativo) indicate [qui](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ITverbs.aspx?v=soddisfare) sono cadute in disuso?

Comment: Sì, la fonte di WordReference deve essere antiquata. Le forme tra parentesi, con l'annotazione "poplare [sic] e regionale", sono quelle normalmente usate al giorno d'oggi.

Comment: Tranne, forse, per il gerundio

Comment: Anche *soddisfanno* è in calo; resiste con più successo il congiuntivo *soddisfaccia*, almeno tra quelli che usano il congiuntivo. Non è purtroppo raro sentire o leggere *soddisfino*.

Comment: Per estensione, lo stesso si può dire di tutti i verbi derivanti dal latino *facere*, come disfare, rarefare, stupefare, benefare, ecc.

Answer (score 2):

**Aggiornamento:**

Nel libro *[Scrivere bene (o quasi)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Mw0Q7ljW5dIC&lpg=PA58&hl=it&pg=PA178#v=twopage&q&f=false)* di Elisabetta Perini (Giunti Editore, 2011) ho trovato questa interessante spiegazione:

> Sono corretti **entrambi**: *soddisfo* e *soddisfaccio*.
>
> Anzi, per il verbo *soddisfare* esiste addirittura una terza forma per la 1ª persona del presente indicativo, che però è meno comune: io ***soddisfò***.

Questo libro ammette "forme parallele" per il presente indicativo, per il futuro semplice e per il condizionale che non erano precedentemente elencate nella risposta e che ho aggiunto adesso.

---

Finalmente posso concludere che le forme normalmente usate al giorno d'oggi sono le seguenti. Non includo i tempi composti perché non hanno niente di speciale: si costruiscono con il verbo avere e il participio passato nel modo usuale.

**infinito**: soddisfare 
**gerundio**: soddisfacendo  
**participio presente**: soddisfacente 
**participio passato**: soddisfatto

**INDICATIVO**

**presente**

```
io soddìsfo/soddisfaccio/soddisfò
tu soddìsfi/soddisfài
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddìsfa
noi soddisfiamo/soddisfacciamo
voi soddisfate
loro, Loro, essi soddìsfano/soddisfànno
```

**imperfetto**

```
io soddisfacevo
tu soddisfacevi
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddisfaceva
noi soddisfacevamo
voi soddisfacevate
loro, Loro, essi soddisfacevano
```

**passato remoto**

```
io soddisfeci
tu soddisfacesti
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddisfece
noi soddisfacemmo
voi soddisfaceste
loro, Loro, essi soddisfecero
```

**futuro semplice**

```
io soddisferò/soddisfarò
tu soddisferai/soddisfarai
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddisferà/soddisfarà
noi soddisferemo/soddisfaremo
voi soddisferete/soddisfarete
loro, Loro, essi soddisferanno/soddisfaranno
```

**CONGIUNTIVO**

**presente**

```
io soddisfaccia/soddisfi
tu soddisfaccia/soddisfi
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddisfaccia/soddisfi
noi soddisfacciamo/soddisfiamo
voi soddisfacciate/soddisfiate
loro, Loro, essi soddisfacciano/soddìsfino
```

**imperfetto**

```
io soddisfacessi
tu soddisfacessi
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddisfacesse
noi soddisfacessimo
voi soddisfaceste
loro, Loro, essi soddisfacessero
```

**CONDIZIONALE**

**presente**

```
io soddisferei/soddisfarei
tu soddisferesti/soddisfaresti
lui, lei, Lei, egli soddisferebbe/soddisfarebbe
noi soddisferemmo/soddisfaremmo
voi soddisfereste/soddisfareste
loro, Loro, essi soddisferebbero/soddisfarebbero
```

**IMPERATIVO**

```
(tu) soddisfai
(lui, lei, Lei, egli) soddisfaccia
(noi) soddisfacciamo
(voi) soddisfate
(loro, Loro, essi) soddisfacciano
```

Comment: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verbi-difficili