# Seconda persona singolare dell'imperativo di "soddisfare" + pronome "lo"/"la"/"li"/"le"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, pronouns

Ho preso in prestito dalla biblioteca il libro di Roberto Tartaglione, ***Verbissimo: tutti i verbi italiani*** (Firenze: Alma Edizioni, 1999), http://www.almaedizioni.it/catalogo/scheda/verbissimo/. Penso si tratti di un buon libro, anche se la coniugazione di tutti i verbi veramente non c'è. Sulla coniugazione del verbo soddisfare, che è stata discussa in [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3521/707), il libro afferma che si può coniugare seguendo il modello del verbo "fare" e aggiunge questa nota:

> Oltre alla coniugazione simile a quella di tutti gli altri composti di fare, dispone anche di una coniugazione autonoma e regolare. Coniugato come composto di fare prende l'accento nella III persona del presente indicativo ("soddisfà", raro) e provoca raddoppiamento consonantico nel pronome assimilato all'imperativo ("soddisfallo", raro).

Il libro non indica qual è questa "coniugazione autonoma e regolare", ma i commenti di [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3521/707) mi hanno reso chiaro che la forma "soddisfà" è ormai caduta in disuso. La mia domanda è: se "soddisfallo"/"soddisfalla"/"soddisfalli"/"soddisfalle" per la seconda persona singolare dell'imperativo più il pronome "lo"/"la"/"li"/"le" sono anche forme rare, quali sarebbero le forme usuali?

Comment: Io direi "soddisfalo", "soddisfali", "soddisfale".

Comment: soddisfalo, soddisfali, soddisfale, soddisfala. Con l'accento sulla "i" come per soddisfa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Soddisfare* è un verbo che, nel tempo, ha accolto numerose forme analogiche nella sua coniugazione. Ciò è dovuto alla crescente opacità della parola, di cui non si riconosce piú la composizione (*soddis* [*satis*] + *fare*).

Il *[DOP](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=14893&r=13987)*, piú fedele alla tradizione, riporta tre forme d’imperativo alla seconda persona singolare:

> imper. **soddisfai** [*soddisfài*] (in procl. **soddisfa’**
>   [*soddisfà*]) o **soddisfà** [id. o *soddisfà+*]

Coerentemente, in unione con un clitico, il verbo si comporta come *fare*, il quale ha tre varianti d’imperativo (*fai*, *fa’* e *fa*) ma, quand’è accompagnato da un clitico, seleziona solo la piú antica, *fa*, che attiva la cogeminazione: *fallo*, *fanne*, *falli*, ecc.

Tuttavia, *soddisfallo*, benché benedetto dalla tradizione, non è forma d’uso comune. L’uso, invece, ha sancito anche in questo caso una forma analogica: l’imperativo è *soddísfa*, con accento sul tema. In unione con un clitico diventa *soddísfalo*.

Il *[De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/soddisfare)* riporta queste forme, ma solo dopo le due piú tradizionali.

> nell’imp. *soddisfai* o *soddisfa’* o *soddisfa*, *soddisfate*

La tendenza è però quella a normalizzare l’intera coniugazione secondo il modello dei verbi in -*are*, perciò non solo è piú comune sentire *soddísfalo* piuttosto che *soddisfàllo*, ma anche altri modi e tempi subiscono l’effetto dell’analogia, come l’imperfetto *soddisfava* per *soddisfaceva* (*soddisfava* è, al momento, una forma sconsigliata).

Comment: È molto difficile trovare esempi di _soddisfallo_. In _Google Libri_, per un difetto nel sistema di riconoscimento caratteri, digitando «soddisfallo» si trovano per lo piú occorrenze di «soddisfatto». A ciò va aggiunta la relativa rarità dell’imperativo di questo verbo, oltre alla confusione con _soddisfallo_ terza persona dell’indicativo presente, con enclisi antica del pronome clitico.